# Get partial node in XPATH

Tags: dom, xpath

Suppose I have the following XML

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <e></e>
</a>
```

If I want to get a all children of **a** except **d**. For that, I would use the following:

```
/a/*[not(self::d)]
```

However, this would return **b**, **c**, and **e** in three separate nodes. What I am looking for is only one node, containing **b**, **c**, and **e**, excluding **d**. It would be something simlar to the following pseudo code:

```
/a/* and <do not include /a/d please>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible in XPath 1.0. For version 2, I do not know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath - no matter whether version 1.0, 2.0 or 3.0 - can only query subtrees and is not capable to modify (which includes removing) or construct new elements.

You would have to use XQuery or XSLT for this purpose, or modify the document outside the query language and only use XPath to select the result subtree, afterwards use another XPath to select the nodes you do not want and remove them from the result in the programming language you're using.