# Xpath - Select all excluding subnode with attribute

Tags: html, regex, xpath

I have a bunch of `<div class="post">` nodes, and i need to select the contents of each, whilst excluding a subnode called `<div class="quote">`.

Example:

```
<div class="post">
<div class="quote"><a href="{url}">some text</div>
some content<br>more content
</div>
```

In this example, select  `"some content<br>more content"` and exclude `<div class="quote">..</div>`

I tried this, doesn't work:

`@doc.xpath("//div[@class='post'][not(self::div)]")`

Comment: Sorry, no duplicate, was too fast. This case is different as the node to remove is on the top-most level and thus can be excluded. [The duplicate case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17566823/get-partial-node-in-xpath/17567661#17567661) is only valid for those with subnodes on arbitrary or non-top level.

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath expression is selecting all `<div/>` elements which are no `<div/>` element, thus it will never return any value. You need an axis step after selecting the "post"-`<div/>`.

Select all subnodes, but exclude those with local name (omitting namespaces) "div" and class attribute "quoe".

```
//div[@class='post']/node()[not(local-name() = 'div' and @class='quote')]
```

You could also use `self::div` instead of the local name test.